# IEqualityComparer<string> for lists

Tags: c#, linq, intersection

I have a list of words `List<string> censored = new List<string> { "heck", "test" };` and I'd like to censor a string word based on if the word contains one of those censored words.

```cs
char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', ',', '.', ':', ';', '-', '!', '?' };
var messageWords = message.Split(delimiterChars, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var containsWordsInMessage = censored.Intersect(messageWords, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

foreach (var item in containsWordsInMessage)
{
    message = message.Replace(item, new string('*', item.Length), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
```

Example message: `This hecking code won't work. :))`

Expected result: `This ******* code won't work. :))`

So, currently, my code looks for the whole word, but how do I combine the .Intersect with a custom equality comparer that will ignore the case and also check for the substring of an item? Because I created `class MyEqualityComparerString : IEqualityComparer<string>`, however, the code below never really enters any of `MyEqualityComparerString`'s methods. Why?

```cs
var result = censored.Intersect(messageWords, new MyEqualityComparerString());
```

Comment: Whoops, my mistake. Added a sample of what I tried, but it never enters the body of any of MyEqualityComparerString's methods, so I wonder why.

Comment: any of the comparer methods? Well, there are actually 2: `Equals` and `GetHashCode`. At least the latter **will** be called. You have to provide some way to return the same hashcode for what you consider to be equal.

Comment: I realized that using `Contains` and `Intersect` won't really work because of `GetHashCode`. :) Nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invert your filtering - you are looking for words in message that are censored, not the censored substrings that are in message. Convert censored to a `HashSet<string>` to speed up the (presumably) common case of the entire word being present. Preconvert the `messageWords` to lower case so you don't have to do it for every `censored` word.

```
var message = "This Hecking Code won't work. :))";
var messageWords = message.Split(delimiterChars, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(w => w.ToLowerInvariant()).ToList();

var censored = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) { "heck", "test" };
var censoredWordsInMessage = messageWords.Where(w => censored.Contains(w) || censored.Any(c => w.Contains(c)));

foreach (var censoredWord in censoredWordsInMessage) {
    message = message.Replace(censoredWord, new string('*', censoredWord.Length), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
```